# How to perform sub aggregation that will calculate fields with no value per bucket?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, dsl, elasticsearch-aggregation

Currently building the following Elasticsearch 6.8 query\aggregation:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "DateCreated": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "InternalEntityId": "ExampleValue1111"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Direction": "Inbound"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "top_ext": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ExternalAddress.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_date": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "DateCreated": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do we perform (in the same search):

- Count the sum of (hits per bucket) that have **no** value (must_not exists style query) PER bucket

Ideally, with the return of the *top_ext* agg return.. each bucket would have a count of the records that have no value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Now you can do two things here, 
1. Either sort the "top_ext" terms agg bucket by asc order of doc count and you can use the top n zero size buckets here
2. You can apply a bucket selector aggregation in parallel to you inner hits so that only those inner hits will appear that have zero docCounts.

Here is a query dsl that uses both the above approaches.(You can plug in all other required elements of the query, I have focused mainly on the aggregation part here)

```
GET kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "outer": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "products.category.keyword",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "_count": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "inner": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        },
        "restrictedBuckets": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "docCount": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.docCount<1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```